# How do I show what the user's rectangle will look like?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, rectangles

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on canvas with a click, a mouse movement, and another click. How should I go about following the user's cursor after the first click and displaying a preview of a filled rectangle on canvas of what the shape would look like at any given coordinate.

So far, I can successfully create the rectangle without showing what the rectangle will look like at any coordinate.

Here is the code so far:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var drawingShape = false;

//function getMousePos(canvas, ev) {
//var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
//}

//canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (ev) {
//var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, ev);
//} 

function setMousePosition(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    $("#downlog").html("Down: " + mouseX + " / " + mouseY);


    if (drawingShape) {
        drawingShape = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.rect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
        ctx.fill();

    } else {
        drawingShape = true;
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;
    }
}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    setMousePosition(e);
});
```

I attempted to use an event listener to mouse movement, as I saw in this HTML5 tutorial (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/), but I'm unsure how to connect it with the existing code.

Comment: jsfiddle from the code you provided (for people trying to help): http://jsfiddle.net/bnkT8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the image whenever you start drawing and reload it everytime you want to edit it.
Here's my quick implementation based on your code, it needs some optimization (perhaps only capture the area you're planning to draw):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var drawingShape = false;
var oldImage;

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  if(drawingShape){
    ctx.putImageData(oldImage,0,0);
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX, 10);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY, 10);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.rect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
    ctx.fill();
  }
});

function setMousePosition(e) {
mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX, 10);
mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY, 10);
$("#downlog").html("Down: " + mouseX + " / " + mouseY);


  if (drawingShape) {
    drawingShape = false;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.rect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
    ctx.fill();

  } else {
    drawingShape = true;
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
    oldImage = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  }
}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    setMousePosition(e);
});
```

Notice how we store the image data in the mouse down event and retrieve it on each mouse move